# Pause/Stop downloading new emails while running VBA macro in Outlook [pause/stop sync]

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm new to VBA Programming in Outlook.

I'm writing a macro which scans inbox and moves emails to specific folders by checking criteria such as subject, sender, body etc.

**Now the problem is that when I loop through the mailbox and a new email comes in, the loop breaks.**

First possible solution to this that came to my head was disabling email synchronization for the time when macro is running. *I researched this further and found the Sync Object in Outlook VBA with the method `Sync.Start` and `Sync.Stop`*.

[docs Microsoft - SyncObject.Start method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.syncobject.start)

So I declared all variables like in the link and tried the code. Everything seems to be executed without errors, `I loop through all the sync objects and stop them` however I noticed that emails come to my inbox anyway.

```
Public Sub Sync() 
 Dim nsp As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim sycs As Outlook.SyncObjects 
 Dim syc As Outlook.SyncObject 
 Dim i As Integer 

Set nsp = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
Set sycs = nsp.SyncObjects 

For i = 1 To sycs.Count 
    Set syc = sycs.Item(i) 
    syc.Stop  
Next 
End Sub
```

Any ideas how to make this work or other ideas how to overcome this problem are greatly appreciated. Thanks

[EDIT 1, 07.05.2020, 20:29] Thanks for your comments guys, I just got another idea in my head. I could create a temporary folder, move all emails that satisfy my criteria from inbox into this temporary folder, sort those emails to other folders from that temp folder. *This should work because no new emails will be coming to the temp folder unlike inbox!*

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, please show your code that processes the items.

Secondly, you can sort your collection (`Items.Sort`) on `ReceivedTime` and process the Items collection backwards (`Items.Count to 1 step -1`)

Comment: This is a great idea actually, haven't thought of that! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating over all items in the folder and don't break the loop when a new item arrives, I'd recommend using the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods where you can find only items that correspond to your conditions. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/)
- [How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/11/outlook-retrieve-calendar-items/)

Also, you can process items by small chunks by finding all items for a week or month and etc.

Comment: I'll have to research this, however the logical part in my code is rather large: sorting more than 100 different types of emails into more than 50 folders. By using combinations of different criteria I'm afraid this would be awfully slow. But when I read on this I'll make a test :) Thanks